# software methodology used in project

Tags: project, agile, methodology

Currently I am working on porting a benchmark application to another system. I am working alone, so I am frustrated about which software methodology I really have to use. Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume you're wondering which Agile approach to use on your project as you tagged your question accordingly.

Agile is mainly about:

- Delivering working software continuously and regularly
- Aiming at technical excellence and avoiding technical debt
- Improving the way we work and retrospecting regularly

I'd say whatever you use, even your very own approach to software development, if you can check those three items from the list, then you're pretty much Agile to me. Some people need strict guidelines and artifacts and that's fine, they help people become Agile but are far from being mandatory despite the dogmas out there.

Here's how I would approach your situation.

1. Take a step back and try to identify the most important features or abilities of this benchmarking application. By most important, I mean those features that the people using it in the end cannot live without. Once you have a list of those, put them on post-it notes, index cards, trello, jira or whatever tool you want to use.
2. Split each of those features into full-stack chunks of functionality that are business driven. I'm not talking about technical tasks here, but smaller features usable by actual people. I usually opt for the "Grandma Driven" approach here, asking myself "would grandma be able to understand what I'm trying to do?". It's just to make sure I'm focusing on a full stack feature and not a technical task like "populate database". One way to see this is also by applying dimensional planning to each of the features you identified (http://www.xpday.net/Xpday2007/session/DimensionalPlanning.html).
3. Set yourself an iteration length (I usually go for 1 or max 2 weeks when I'm working alone) and get to work one small item at a time. Don't write code for later, only what you need to solve the problem at hand. Quality is not an option. Focus on good coding and testing practices.
4. At the end of your iteration, check how many features you implemented and put that number somewhere on a chart, in a google spreadsheet or whatever. This will help you see if you're on track. Get feedback from colleagues or any potential users of the system and reflect on that feedback. It's not because you're porting to another platform that you can't make it better.
5. If you end up not having small enough granularity with what's left or not enough stuff in your list of things to do, spend some time repeating steps 1 to 3.
6. At the end of each iteration, keep tracking how many items you did just to see if you still have a good enough pace. If not, ask yourself why and change something in the way you work or get help. Again, your main focus is to make progress and deliver software that works at the end of each iteration.

It might not answer your question and I know I didn't give you an answer of the type, use kanban, scrum or whatever but I truly believe it's not appropriate in your specific case and would only generate overhead and boredom for you.

Hope that helps anyway, good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. It will be helpful to me in the future. :)